# Including custom blueprint templates

Tags: fiware-pegasus

I would like to upload my own blueprint templates, then teploy blueprint instanced based on them. Can FIWARE Pegasus do that? In positive case, could you detail the procedure, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your own blueprint template into the FIWARE template catalogue, by using the Pegasus API (see https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/fiwarepaas/reference/paasmanager-v1/blueprint-templateenvironment-api.html).

It is a POST request to /catalog/org/{your-organization}/vdc/{your tenant id in the Cloud}/environment with a payload similar to:

Body

```
<environment>
    <name>{environment-name}</name>
    <tiers>
        <tier>
            <initial_number_instances>1</initial_number_instances>
            <maximum_number_instances>1</maximum_number_instances>
            <minimum_number_instances>1</minimum_number_instances>
            <name>{tier-id}</name>
            <networkDto>
                    <networkName>Internet</networkName>
                    <subNetworkDto>
                            <subnetName>sub-net-Internet</subnetName>
                    </subNetworkDto>
            </networkDto>
            <productReleases>
                <product>postgresql</product>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <withArtifact>true</withArtifact>
                <productType>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <name>Database</name>
                </productType>
            </productReleases>
        </tier>
    </tiers>
</environment>
```